# На сколько примерно градусов может варьироваться температура ssd на интерфейсе pci-e 2.0/pci-e 3.0

Tags: ssd

Хотел приобрести samsung 970 pro 512gb, интерфейс ноута asus n751jx pci-e 2.0 x4. У ssd диска в температура в простое около 50 градусов. Сколько градусов можно выиграть на медленном интерфейсе? (на мой взгляд температура явно должна быть ниже в момент передачи файлов, но температура простоя измениться почти не должна)